# Op amp AC simple supple (Buffer) LM324N

Tags: operational-amplifier, orcad, single-supply-op-amp, virtual-ground

I´m working on a proyect and i use OrCad/Spice to simulate the op amp that i gone use and my Voltage(output) signal is Constant and my Voltage(Input) is sinusoidal.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your OpAmp's power supplies are connected upside down. You've put Vcc on V- and GND on V+.

Comment: Hm, what is your question?

Comment: Your professor should be giving you guys a bit more help before sending you here.

Answer (score 3):

For the LM324 (and most 14 pin quad opamps), pin 4 is the positive supply and pin 11 the negative. Swap them round, then try again.

Comment: Works i didnt notice that